# Calculating age is not accurate

Tags: android

I want to update users age when the calculated age is greater than the current age it will update the DB.
this is the piece of code that calculates the age but it's not accurate.

I'm retrieving the dob via Sharedpreferences and it is:
27-07-1993 the age should be 27 but it prints out 26.
any ideas to make it calculate accurately? Thanks in advance.

```
    private int getAge(){
        String userDob = SharedPrefManager.getUserDob();
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(userDob);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(date == null) return 0;

        Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        dob.setTime(date);

        int year = dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = dob.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        dob.set(year, month+1, day);

        int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
            age--;
        }
        Log.i(CalcAge, "my age " + age);
        return age;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private int getAge(){
        String userDob = SharedPrefManager..getUserDob();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", LOCALE_DEFAULT);
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(userDob);

            Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
            today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
            dob.setTime(date);

            int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            Calendar birthDayThisYear = Calendar.getInstance();
            birthDayThisYear.set(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), dob.get(Calendar.MONTH), dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            birthDayThisYear.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            birthDayThisYear.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            birthDayThisYear.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            birthDayThisYear.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            if (today.before(birthDayThisYear)) {
                age--;
            }

            return age;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```